# Run a function in parellel in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . import x
def index(request):
    return render(request,'a.html', {})
```

This is `x.py`

```
def y()
    while(True):
        print("X")
y()
```

Currently the `while` loop takes all resources and blocks Django from serving `a.html`
I need to run Django and `x.py` simultaneously.They are unrelated.How should do I that?

I am stuck on this for 3 days.Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) to do this.
2 just call:

```py
python x.py && python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: `python x.py && python manage.py runserver` This froze the `Django` .So I ran `Django` & `x.py` as two separate processes.While deploying to `Heroku`,I will simply define two processes in `Procfile`

Answer (score 0):

I think as you already know there are two solutions to your problem.

1. If your view response depends on results from x and x is external IO . Then you should use following
   May be you want to checkout this
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/
2. But if your views response doesn't depend on results from x but you want x to run as separate process ( on same or different machine ) you can definitely use process. But you will have to install django celery to use this functionality

You can modify x.py as following . Arguments is provided just as example

```
@app.task
 def y(arg1):
      print(arg1):
```

then your django view can be updated:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .x import y
def index(request):
    y.apply_async([value_for_arg1]) or y.delay(value_for_arg1)
    return render(request,'a.html', {})
```

Then you need to start two different processes

- python manage.py runserver
- celery -A app_name worker -l INFO

You will also need to use rabbitmq/db/redis as your message queue. But its highly scalable solution

Comment: Could you please provide an example code or tutorial link? Thanks

Comment: Check this one looks good https://deepsource.io/blog/django-async-support/ , I will try to update my answer in another 12 hrs